# I need explanation for a meaning of "was on borrowed time"

Tags: meaning, expressions, american-english, sentence, time

I'm studying English and I know a lot of words and wanted to read a book for my first time in English but there is sentence in the beginning of it that I can't really understand the meaning:

> And now, unbeknownst to him, Ed Warren was on borrowed time.

I googled it but I can't get the meaning of the " **was on borrowed time**".

Comment: Have you checked for [borrowed time](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/borrowed%20time)?

Comment: I did , but it seems to me that the meaning does not make sense in this sentence. Does it mean he got saved from death and now he has a second chance to live now ? Or he has limited time to live ?

Comment: You will have to read on to find out! You haven't told us what book it is, so we can't guess.

Comment: "The Demonologist: The Extraordinary Career of Ed and Lorraine Warre " it's this book

Answer (score 3):

[The dictionary says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/borrowed%20time):

> an uncertain and usually uncontrolled postponement of something inevitable

For example:

> The doctors gave him six months to live. That was seven months ago, so he is *living on borrowed time*.

The end is inevitable but it has been delayed. We don't know by how much.

It can be a metaphorical death.

> The resignations in the cabinet reveal a level of discontent so strong that the Prime Minister cannot remain in office for much longer. He is *living on borrowed time.*

The Prime Minister will surely have to resign or be voted out, but we don't know when.

Answer (score 0):

Think of borrowed time as with borrowed money.

I had run out of money and should have been kicked out of the house, but the money others lent me allowed me to continue a bit longer.

Similarly, Ed Warren was on borrowed time, meaning that he should have died already, but time had been figuratively lent to him to keep living.

Answer (score 0):

*On borrowed time* means the primary expected death time has ended but the person continues to live. That time after expected time of death is referred to as “borrowed”.

In medicine, if a person has a disease that kills most people in one year but that person is somehow still alive 2 years later, the last year would be borrowed time. On death row, if a person was ordered to be put to death on Jan 1, 2022 but received a stay from the governor on December 31,2021, all time he is alive AFTER Jan 1,2022 is “borrowed time”.

Answer (score -1):

It means to continue alive after one expected to die. It can be used, for example, when someone survived a terrible accident or a serious illness.

Comment: You answer should include a supporting reference to confirm your definition.